# Difference in combinations between dictionary and grammatical structure

Tags: combinatorics

Based on [this question](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/30828/20729), I'm trying to work out how much worse a passphrase with a grammatical structure is compared to a passphrase made up of a random bunch of words. Is my maths correct in this worked example (and thus, my overarching logic for counting combinations in phrases)?

Assume a dictionary containing a total of **19010** words, broken up like so:

- 3000 *nouns*, each with plural forms (`3000 * 2 = 6000`)
- 1500 *verbs*, each with 4 tenses and plural forms (`1500 * 4 * 2 = 12000`)
- 1000 *adjectives*, no additional variations (`= 1000`)
- 10 *determiners*, made up of:

  - the articles `the` and `a`
  - the demonstratives `this` and `that`
  - the personal pronouns `my`, `your`, `their`, `his`, `her`, `its`

<sup>I realise some words don't have all 4 tenses or plural forms, but it shouldn't matter too much for my reasoning.</sup>

### Grammar

Assume I'm going to generate a phrase based on the structure: `det noun verb det adjective noun`. And assume I'll choose words based on a uniform distribution, and I won't re-use words.

```
total combinations = 
    count(determiners) 
    * count(noun forms) 
    * count(verb forms) 
    * count(adjective) 
    * count(determiners) 
    * (count(noun forms) - 1)
= 10 * 6000 * 12000 * 1000 * 10 * (6000-1)
~ 4.32E+16 (~ 55.3 bits)
```

And without the determiners:

```
~ 4.32E+14 (~ 48.6 bits)
```

### Random Words

Assume I'll choose 4 words at random (representing the 4 major forms from the grammar version), also based on uniform distribution, and don't re-use words.

```
total combinations = 
    count(all forms) 
    * (count(all forms) - 1)
    * (count(all forms) - 2)
    * (count(all forms) - 3)
= 19010 * (19010-1) * (19010-2) * (19010-3)
~ 1.31E+17 (~ 56.9 bits)
```

And if I choose 6 words (same number of words as when determiners are included):

```
~ 4.72E+25 (~ 85.3 bits)
```

(I'm sure there's a proper notation for this pattern (NPR?? permutations?? combinations??), but my high school maths have long deserted me).

### Differences

All in orders of base 10 magnitude.

```
                    Grammar   Random Words   Diff
No-Det vs 4 words    14        17             2
Det vs 4 words       16        17             1
No-Det vs 6 words    14        25             11
Det vs 6 words       16        25             9
```

And, just to repeat my question: is my math and logic correct here?

And a bonus question: what's a "fair" comparison between numbers of words / determiners, because that makes all the difference (though that's probably a question for the security StackOverflow)? My thinking here is the determiners are all pretty short (1-5 letters), so they're probably equivalent to 1 but not 2 extra words, which gives 5-6 orders of magnitude difference.

Comment: It seems fine to me, except, since you're using English as an example, the adjective should come after the determiner ;-)

Comment: Woops. Fixed that word order! You might as well pad out your "yes" into a more substantial answer!